# Replica set and shard in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, shared-libraries, replicaset

i am new in mongodb. i am facing issue with getting data using asp.net mvc web api. i am getting data but it's take too much time. in my database more than 500 million data(20-30 million data every day inserted). so using replica set and shard is it possible to write and read data fast?

below is my web api code

```
var query = Query.And(
    Query<obscls>.EQ(u => u.no, "no"),
    Query<obscls>.GT(u => u.CreatedDate, Convert.ToDateTime(startdate)),
    Query<obscls>.LT(u => u.CreatedDate, Convert.ToDateTime(enddate))
    );

var data = obs.Find(query).ToList();


var oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
oSerializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(data);

return json = JObject.Parse("{'ListData':" + sJSON + "}");
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have update my question with code(query).

Answer (score 1):

1: A replica set is unlikely to help spread the load of all your data inserts; the [docs on replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#replication-in-mongodb) make it clear that:

> Of the data bearing nodes, one and only one member is deemed the primary node, while the other nodes are deemed secondary nodes.
>
> The primary node receives all write operations.

However, note that you should be using replication anyway - it is necessary for high-availability and resilience.

2: [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#advantages-of-sharding) *might* help with spreading the workload:

> Both read and write workloads can be scaled horizontally across the cluster by adding more shards.

However, sharding is both difficult to implement well and whether you get any benefit depends on the shape of your data and the way you shard it. You might find that, rather than investing in the extra hardware and extra configuration for sharding, you might get more value from upgrading your hardware to use hardware with faster I/O, for example.